# (Java Minecraft 1.14) Loot table reward won't stack with /given item, even though they have the same nbt?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I have an item in a datapack which has a supplemental function to give it straight to the player (for testing), and an entry in a loot table (which is how survival players get it). I recently noticed that these two items will not stack, under any circumstances, even though they should have *the exact same* nbt  data. The `/give` command looks like this:

```
give @s minecraft:quartz{dmd_dark_quartz:1b,CustomModelData:256,display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Dark Quartz\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"}} 1
```

While the loot table looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:item",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "condition": "random_chance",
      "chance": 0.75
    }
  ],
  "functions": [
    {
      "function": "set_name",
      "name": {"text":"Dark Quartz","color":"dark_purple","italic":"false"}
    },
    {
      "function": "set_nbt",
      "tag": "{dmd_dark_quartz:1b,CustomModelData:256}"
    },
    {
       "function": "minecraft:explosion_decay"
    }
  ],
  "name": "minecraft:quartz"
}
```

When I hold the two items in my hand and use `/data get entity @s SelectedItem`, the only difference is that there are no quotes surrounding the false value for italics in the loot table version. Here's a picture for further clarification of what I mean:
[image: data get screenshot]
I underlined the `false` values that were different. Does anyone know if this is a bug or what causes this? I think it's probably a bug because all other values (`"dark_purple"`, for example) have the quotes, but that singular one doesn't. Is it because it is a true/false value and doesn't need quotes? I would prefer if they stacked because then testing would be easier and I wouldn't have to test both versions for everything, but not including quotes in the `/give` command seems a bit sacrilegious.

Upon further testing, not including the quotes in the `/give` command gives an item that has the *exact* same nbt (so the `/data get` looks exactly the same) as the loot table version but **still** doesn't stack with either one.

Any answers on why this is happening?

Comment: I'll put a link to a datapack with the function and loot table in case anyone is interested tomorrow morning.

Comment: The JSON is just a string for the game, so the order of keys matters. (Did that already answer your question? Then I'll write a lame answer. ;) )

Comment: @Fabian In both commands, the order is the same: text, color, italic. I'll try that in the third command however, because I don't remember if I put them in the same order (although I thought I did).

Comment: Your screenshot shows "italic text color" and "italic color text".

Comment: @Fabian That must be it, but I have no idea why that happens. The commands/loot table all go 'text color italic', so maybe Minecraft reorganizes NBT internally? When I get back I'll try changing the order in the command and seeing if the values have switched.

Comment: This seems like something that has to do with NBT being scanned more than one time inside of minecraft if its not inside of quotes. Try putting it inside quotes and see if they stack then.

Answer (score 1):

Try using set_nbt function only like:

```
  "function": "set_nbt",
  "tag": "{display:{Name:'{\"text\":\"Dark Quartz\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"italic\":false}'},CustomModelData:1}"
```

I was testing it on wandering traders trades and it worked! Name, color and italic option are exatly the same arregment as from /give command.

Answer (score 0):

`false` is not supposed to be in quotes.